# React Js renderings is functionalities not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react . I am hared coded the username and password into js pages . I am trying to redirect to user into admin pages on the text fields values. Here is mentioned that username and password Admin then i want to redirect the user into admin page else into home page but is not working . I also defined the router as well into app.js files.

Here is the app.js .

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { history } from '../_helpers';
import { alertActions } from '../_actions';
import { PrivateRoute } from '../_components';
import { HomePage } from '../HomePage';
import { LoginPage } from '../LoginPage';
import { RegisterPage } from '../RegisterPage';
import CreateEmployeeComponent  from '../EmployeeComponets/CreateEmployeeComponent';
import ViewEmployeeComponent from '../EmployeeComponets/ViewEmployeeComponent';
import AdminComponent from '../EmployeeComponets/AdminComponent';


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // clear alert on location change
            this.props.clearAlerts();
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="jumbotron">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        {alert.message &&
                            <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>{alert.message}</div>
                        }
                        <Router history={history}>
                            <Switch>
                                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                                <Route path = "/add-employee/:id" component = {CreateEmployeeComponent} />
                               <Route path = "/view-employee/:id" component = {ViewEmployeeComponent} />
                          
                                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                                <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
                                <Route path ="/admin" component={AdminComponent} />

                                <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
                            </Switch>
                        </Router>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapState(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return { alert };
}

const actionCreators = {
    clearAlerts: alertActions.clear
};

const connectedApp = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

Here is the code for Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // reset login status
        this.props.logout();

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { username, password } = this.state;
        if (username && password) {
            this.props.login(username, password);
        }
        else if(username==="Admin" && password==="Admin"){
            localStorage.setItem("token" , "shjsshhbhbh")
            this.setState({
                loggingIn:true
              
            })

        }
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.loggingIn){
            return <Redirect to ="/admin" />
        }
        const { loggingIn } = this.props;
        const { username, password, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !username ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !username &&
                            <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !password ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !password &&
                            <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        {loggingIn &&
                            
                        }
                        <Link to="/register" className="btn btn-link">Register</Link>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapState(state) {
    const { loggingIn } = state.authentication;
    return { loggingIn };
}

const actionCreators = {
    login: userActions.login,
    logout: userActions.logout
};

const connectedLoginPage = connect(mapState, actionCreators)(LoginPage);
export { connectedLoginPage as LoginPage };
```

Here is the private route code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('user')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)
```

Here is the admin page .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';

class AdminComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        
        super(props)
        const token =localStorage.getItem("token")
        let loggedIn = true
        {
            if(token == null){
                loggedIn - false
            }
            this.state ={
                loggedIn
            }
        }

        this.state = {
            // step 2
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            emailId: ''
        }
        this.changeFirstNameHandler = this.changeFirstNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.changeLastNameHandler = this.changeLastNameHandler.bind(this);
        this.saveOrUpdateEmployee = this.saveOrUpdateEmployee.bind(this);
    }

    // step 3
    componentDidMount(){

        // step 4
        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            return
        }else{
            EmployeeService.getEmployeeById(this.state.id).then( (res) =>{
                let employee = res.data;
                this.setState({firstName: employee.firstName,
                    lastName: employee.lastName,
                    emailId : employee.emailId
                });
            });
        }        
    }
    saveOrUpdateEmployee = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let employee = {emailId: this.state.emailId,firstName: this.state.firstName, lastName: this.state.lastName};
        console.log('employee => ' + JSON.stringify(employee));

        // step 5
        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            EmployeeService.createEmployee(employee).then(res =>{
                this.props.history.push('/employees');
            });
        }else{
            EmployeeService.updateEmployee(employee, this.state.id).then( res => {
                this.props.history.push('/employees');
            });
        }
    }
    
    changeFirstNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({firstName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeLastNameHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({lastName: event.target.value});
    }

    changeEmailHandler= (event) => {
        this.setState({emailId: event.target.value});
    }

    cancel(){
        this.props.history.push('/employees');
    }

    getTitle(){
        if(this.state.id === '_add'){
            return <h3 className="text-center">Add Employee</h3>
        }else{
            return <h3 className="text-center">Update Employee</h3>
        }
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.loggedIn === false)
        {
            return <Redirect to ="/login" />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to adimin </h1>
                <br></br>
                   <div className = "container">
                        <div className = "row">
                            <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                                {
                                    this.getTitle()
                                }
                                <div className = "card-body">
                                    <form>
                                    <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Email Id: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Email Address" name="emailId" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.emailId} onChange={this.changeEmailHandler}/>
                                                </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> First Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.changeFirstNameHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className = "form-group">
                                            <label> Last Name: </label>
                                            <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" className="form-control" 
                                                value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.changeLastNameHandler}/>
                                        </div>
                                       
                                    

                                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveOrUpdateEmployee}>Save</button>
                                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</button>
                                        
                                         
             
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                   </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AdminComponent
```

Comment: Please also share `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: Added the private route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `handleSubmit` function always first `if` is true and after that javascript didn't check another `else if`.

Also you need add another state `isAdmin` and use it like this:

```
const { username, password } = this.state;
if (username==="Admin" && password==="Admin") {
    this.props.login(username, password);
    localStorage.setItem("token" , "adminsaddad")
    this.setState({
        loggingIn:true,
        isAdmin:true
    })
} else if (username && password) {
    this.props.login(username, password);
    localStorage.setItem("token" , "shjsshhbhbh")
    this.setState({
        loggingIn:true
    })
}
```

Then check if the user is admin or not:

```
if(this.state.loggingIn){
    if(this.state.isAdmin)
      return <Redirect to ="/admin" />
    else 
      return <Redirect to ="/" />
}
```

But this is not a safe way for the admin page, should also add the admin component in your PrivateRoute and check the token then redirect user.

Comment: but the problem is what ever username and password i am passing into input fileds its redirect to admin page not home page

Comment: Check answer now!

Comment: same result but others users can not login. I am reusing the code from this link . https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example

Comment: Its intially goes to admin page but after 3 seconds redirect to normal user page . I added the admin page as well

Comment: Your form and redux action have some problem, you should make a codesandbox ill help you with that.